# Issues with ESLint "max-len" ignore pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, eslint

I'm trying to ignore import statements with the ESLint "max-len" rule and some ES6 code. My rule set is written in a config in `index.js` and the config for the rule itself looks like this:

```
    'max-len': [
        2,
        80,
        4,
        {
            ignoreUrls: true,
            ignorePattern: /^import\s.+\sfrom\s.+;$/
        }
    ],
```

Lines exceeding 80 characters still trigger errors given the RegExp I've provided. Is there something I'm not understanding about the rule itself?

I've also tried simpler RegExps and passing RegExp strings such as:

```
'^import.*'
```

Found here: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len

Comment: What if you remove the `$`? It's not obvious if the line contains trailing `\n` or `\r` or not.

Comment: Define "doesn't like"? Have you tried passing it as a string with double-escaping like the examples in the docs show? e.g. `ignorePattern: "^import\\s.+\\sfrom\\s.+;$"`

Comment: It seems that even if I make it very general, something like `/^import*/`, it still fails

Comment: @loganfsmyth, yes, I've tried passing strings as well. The documentation says if you are using JSON or YAML, you need to pass a string. Nevertheless, it still fails with "^import*".

Comment: @loganfsmyth in the sources it is used as `ignorePattern = new RegExp(ignorePattern);` so it can be either.

Comment: @BTC hack the max-len.js - add the output for the line and see why it fails.

Answer (score 19):

I was having trouble with this as well, but @loganfsmyth's suggestion worked for me. I'm using v3.14.0 and all my rules are in an `.eslintrc` file:

```
{
  ...
  "rules": {
    "max-len": [1, 80, 2, {
      "ignorePattern": "^import\\s.+\\sfrom\\s.+;$",
      "ignoreUrls": true
    }],
    ...
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to loganfsmyth's comment and ericgio's answer, but without double-escaping, this worked for me with yaml:

```
rules:
  ...
  max-len:
  - error
  - code: 80
    tabWidth: 2
    ignorePattern: ^import\s.+\sfrom\s.+;$
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, as we have soft-wrap lines on reach of max line to next line by IntelliJ IDE slightly updated change to `.eslintrc` file works good:

```
            "max-len": [
                "error",
                {
                    "code": 180,
                    "ignorePattern":"^(import\\s.+\\sfrom\\s.+|\\} from)",
                    "ignoreUrls": true
                }
            ]
```

That allows us to avoid lint issues with imports that moved to few lines, like:

```
import {
    InvitationBookingSecondColumnComponent
} from './component/booking/invitation-booking/invitation-booking-second-column/invitation-booking-second-column.component';
```